# How to conver the video recorder file to Binary data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video

I'm going to analyze the video while it is recording.
I have analyzing function to analyze the video.
But it needs the binary data of video.
What can i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the sample buffer delegate on the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` object of your `AVCaptureSession`. Make sure what ever you set as the sample buffer delegate adopts the following protocol, `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. Below is an example of how you would set the sample buffer delegate assuming the object you called it from adopts the protocol I mentioned.

```
  [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Then the you need to implement the following method

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

This will be called by your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` object and the binary data of the video will be in `sampleBuffer`.

Note `sampleBuffer` will only contain a slice of the data.

Comment: I'm happy of your answer. Use this it is possible to put the video recorded data on iphone?

Comment: Sorry I cant understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: use this way can i save data on iphone and load from iphone?